# Change Fields language

Tags: project-server

Is there any method to change `Custom fields` language from default created language to the English language automatically when switch site language to English ?

Any help would be very much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately **No** , In Project Server, only the `Build-In fields` like `Project Name` , `Start Date` that will be changed .

[image]

But `Custom Fields` will still be shown with the default language that you have used to create your these fields whether you switch the site language to English.

[image]